# How many viwers will i get with Wowza or Red5

Tags: stream, red5, rtmp, wowza

If i have 100 down and 10 up internet connection and i stream one channel from my server on 2000 kps and 30 bitrate how many viwers will i get? What is the limit for 10 up internet connection? How can i calculate it? Im thinking about stream with RTMP Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

upstream divided by channel stream is the absolute maximum I  guess, in your case 10/2 = 5 viewers. In practice probably less...

Answer (score 0):

You will get 4 users maximum.

First, You need to downscale your stream to 700-800 kbps first, because 2 mbit is too high for internet.

Second, you need to rent a server on hosting with at least 100 mbit connection, to raise number of users to 100-200